# Calculate combined standard deviation

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, physics

If I have a data that I fit with `NonlinearModelfit` that fits a data based on two fitting parameters, `c1` and `c2`.

When I used `nlm["ParameterTable"] // Quiet` I get the following table:

[image]

If I have an equation such as:

`eq = (2.303*((70 + 273.15)^2)*(c1/c2))/1000`

Is there any code (as opposed to doing it manually) I can use to calculate the value of `eq` with the combined standard deviation based on the standard deviations of `c1` and `c2` from the table?.

To clarify I would like to get something like: `eq = (2.303*((70 + 273.15)^2)*(8.08318/21.1577))/1000=103.604` but also the standard deviation based on the errors of `c1` and `c2` as to get something like `103.604 +- standard error`

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

For reference `eq` comes from:

```
eq = ((log10q - Log10[qref]) == c1*(Tfp - Tfpref)/(c2 + (Tfp - Tfpref)));
model = Tfp /. Solve[eqn, Tfp][[1]]// FullSimplify;
const = {Tfpref -> 70, qref -> 10/60};
model2 = model /. (const // Rationalize) // FullSimplify;

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, {model2, c1 > 5, c2 > 5}, {c1, c2}, 
  log10q];
```

where everything in `eq` is known except the fitting parameters `c1` and `c2`

Comment: Perhaps `eq /.nlm["BestFitParameters"]`?

Comment: Are you wanting `eq` or an estimate of the standard error for `eq`?

Comment: @JimB what I want is for instance to have the value of `eq = (2.303*((70 + 273.15)^2)*(8.08318/21.1577))/1000=103.604` but also the standard deviation based on the errors of c1 and c2 as to get something like `103.604 +- standard error`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann using `eq /.nlm["BestFitParameters"]` only gives me the value of `eq` (e.g. 103.604) but not its standard error. In other words, it does not give me something like `103.604 +- standard error`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're wanting an estimate of the standard error for `eq`, one approach is to use the Delta Method (a.k.a Propagation of Error if you're in the physical sciences).

```
(* Data from first example in `NonlinearModelFit` documentation *)
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}, {6, 4}, {7, 5}};
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, Log[c1 + c2 x^2], {c1, c2}, x]

eq = (2.303*((70 + 273.15)^2)*(c1/c2))/1000
(* (271.183 c1)/c2 *)
eq /. nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* 286.391 *)

f = D[eq, {{c1, c2}}] /. nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {190.126, -200.789} *)
se = (f.nlm["CovarianceMatrix"].f)^0.5
(* 261.115 *)
```

More work but better if the desired function estimator does not have an approximate normal distribution is to use a bootstrap approach.

**Addition:**

I should note that the true standard error almost certainly doesn't exist as the ratio of two normals have no finite moments.  However, the "estimate of the standard error" can (depending on the values of the distributions of the estimators) provide a reasonable confidence interval for the estimate of the ratio (such as in +/- 1.96 standard errors).

Comment: Thanks JimB. When I use the last line of your code I get this error: `FittedModel::constr: The property values {CovarianceMatrix} assume an unconstrained model. The results for these properties may not be valid, particularly if the fitted parameters are near a constraint boundary`. Is there something I should modify from the code?

Comment: I am using your code like this: `eq = (2.303*((70 + 273.15)^2)*((c1 /. nlm["BestFitParameters"])/(c2 /.nlm["BestFitParameters"])))/1000`; `eq /. nlm["BestFitParameters"]`; `f = D[eq, {{c1, c2}}] /. nlm["BestFitParameters"]`; `se = (f.nlm["CovarianceMatrix"].f)^0.5`

Comment: I think perhaps the mistake is in the line `f = D[eq, {{c1, c2}}] /. nlm["BestFitParameters"]` as I get `{0,0}` as an output from this line.

Comment: I've included a dataset so now the code is complete (and works as advertised).  My guess is that you must have defined `c1` and `c2` previous to `f = D[eq, {{c1, c2}}] /. nlm["BestFitParameters"]`.

Comment: thank you very much for your help !!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the c1/c2 estimates came from a large sample, the `eq` has a non-central ratio of Gaussians distribution. You'd have to simulate or use `NExpectation` here:

```
dc1 = NormalDistribution[8.08318, 0.692171];
dc2 = NormalDistribution[21.1577, 3.13379];
td = TransformedDistribution[(2.303*((70 + 273.15)^2)*(c1/c2))/1000
     , {c1 \[Distributed] dc1, c2 \[Distributed] dc2}];

(* random experiment *)
tdrvts = RandomVariate[td, 1000000];
Histogram[tdrvts]
StandardDeviation[tdrvts] (* around 19.2 *)

(* attempt a near-exact mean and stddev *)
meanEst = NExpectation[x, x \[Distributed] td] (* 106.046 *)
mseEst = Sqrt[Quiet@NExpectation[(x - meanEst)^2, x \[Distributed] td]] (* 19.4 *)
```

Comment: None of the moments exist for the ratio of two normals.  So using `NExpectation` might end up giving one much too large a value depending on the values of the parameters of the two normal distributions.  However, despite that condition the "estimated variance" can many times be used to construct reasonably accurate confidence intervals.

Comment: @JimB The 19.4 looks like an overestimate compared to the random experiment, so you're probably right - I've also hushed up the `NExpectation` with `Quiet` because it was warning me about convergence.

Comment: Warnings are good things.  We should listen to them more than what we usually do.  (I should heed that advice more often than I do.)

Comment: @JimB [indeed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therac-25) "_...so the operator pressed the P key to override the warning and proceed anyway..._"